# Booking flight api with multi-departure , multi-arrival and maximum price feature?

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I'm searching for an api that permits flight booking info searching, with at least a maximum price filter and something like a multi departure/arrival feature:

Departure (London,Paris)
Arrival (Rome,Madrid)

I know that is it an unsual way to search a flight , i have found a very food api at skyscanner but they don't have this features but only a "Anywhere" option. Someone knows other api service with those features?

Comment: use flightstatusAPi, flightawareApi

Comment: flightstatus and flightaware don't include booking information